# Form is getting submitted even when validate rules are failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

Thank you for looking at the question.

Here, i am trying to validate a signup form and using this plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

```
            <form id = 'signupForm' name ='signupForm' method='post' action='/signupUser'>
                <table class='bttable'>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "fName" name = "fName" class ='ep' type = "textbox" placeholder="Given Name"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorfName' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "mName" name = "mName" class ='ep' type = "textbox" placeholder="Middle Name"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errormName' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "lName"  name = "lName" class ='ep' type = "textbox" placeholder="Family Name"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorlName' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "email"  name = "email" class ='ep' type = "email" placeholder="Email:"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                    <td>
                            <div id='erroremail' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "cEmail" name = "cEmail" class ='ep' type = "email" placeholder="Retype Email:"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorcEmail' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "passwd" name = "passwd" class ='ep' type = "password" placeholder="Password:"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorpasswd' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "rPasswd" name = "rPasswd" class ='ep' type = "password" placeholder="Retype Password:"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorrPasswd' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <br>
                            <input id = "login" name = "login" class ='loginButton' type = "submit" value="Submit"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>             
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#signupForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    fName: {
                        required: true,
                        accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
                    },
                    mName: {
                        required: false,
                        accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
                    },
                    lName: {
                        required: true,
                        accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    cEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        equalTo: '#email'
                    },
                    passwd: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    },
                    rPasswd: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8,
                        equalTo: '#passwd'
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    fName: "Please enter valid name.",
                    mName: "Please enter valid name.",
                    lName: "Please enter valid name.",
                    email: "Please enter valid email.",
                    cEmail: {
                        email: "Please enter valid email.",
                        equalTo: "It doesn't match with email."
                    },
                    passwd: {
                        required: "Please enter your password",
                        minlength: "Minlength has to be 8"
                    },
                    rPasswd: {
                        required: "Please enter your password",
                        minlength: "Minlength has to be 8",
                        equalTo: "Doesn't match with password field."
                    }
                },

                errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
                    var name = $element.attr("name");
                    $("#error" + name).append($error);
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    alert('valid form submit');
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

but it's submitting the form even when rules are failing.

Similar login form below on the other hand is working as expected

```
            <form id = 'loginForm' name ='loginForm' method='post' action = "/loginUser">
                <table class='bttable'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='btheight btalign fb'><a href="/auth/facebook" class='socialLink'>Sign in with Facebook</a></td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'><a href="/auth/twitter">Login with Twitter</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='btheight btalign go'><a href="/auth/google">Login with Google</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='line'>–––––––––––– OR ––––––––––––</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "email" name = "email" class ='ep' type='email' placeholder="Your Email" required></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='erroremail' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td class='btheight btalign tw'>
                            <input id = "passwd" name = "passwd" class ='ep' type = "password" placeholder="Your Password" required></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td>
                            <div id='errorpasswd' class='errorclass'></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td >
                            <br>
                            <input id = "login"  name='login' class ='loginButton' type = "submit" value="Submit"></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#loginForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    passwd: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                    passwd: {
                        required: "Please enter your password",
                        minlength: "Minlength has to be 8"
                    }
                },

                errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
                    var name = $element.attr("name");
                    $("#error" + name).append($error);
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    alert('valid form submit');
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Also any suggestion for rules ?

Thanks

Comment: Your submit button has 2 id attribute

Comment: Thank you. It still doesnt work and i updated the question so that anyone else can't get distracted by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML markup...

```
<input id = "fName" name = "fName" class ='ep' type = "textbox" placeholder="Given Name"></input>
```

1)  Should be `type="text"`, not `textbox`.  AFAIK, there is no such thing as `type="textbox"`.

2)  `input` elements are "self-closing", not containers, and there is no such thing as a closing input tag (`</input>`).

**Invalid**:  `<input></input>`

**Valid**:  `<input />`

**Valid**:  `<input>`

Tip:  All those extra spaces are inconsistent, unnecessary and not typically how you'd write HTML markup.  It's also good to be consistent with the type of quotation marks, single or double.

cleaned up:

```
<input id="fName" name="fName" class="ep" type="text" placeholder="Given Name" />
```

---

Inside your `rules` option...

```
fName: {                // <- this is a type="text" input
    required: true,
    accept: "[a-zA-Z]+" // <- accept is only for type="file" inputs
},
...
```

1) [The `accept` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/) is *only* for setting the MIME Types for files uploaded with a  `<input type="file" />` element, not regex for `text` inputs.

2) If you want to use a regex, then you'll need the `pattern` method and you must also include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js).

```
fName: {                
    required: true,
    pattern: "[a-zA-Z]+"
},
...
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fE3DG/**

---

**EDIT**:

The OP never asked about regex and only stated that validation was submitting the form without showing any errors, so that's what this question answered.  Based on comments below, assuming the OP wants to match only upper & lower case letters, change the regex pattern to this...

```
pattern: "^[A-z]+$"
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fE3DG/1/**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the changes using the text and input suggestions you gave.

the pattern still doesnt work. It's still passing the abc123 in name.

Comment: @AjGauravdeep, so simply fix your regex to do what you want.  Your question is titled:  _"Form is getting submitted even when validate rules are failing"_ and that's what I fully answered correctly.

Comment: @AjGauravdeep, see the updated answer and demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/fE3DG/1/ ~  I made some assumptions since you never said anything about your desired regex pattern.

Comment: You are right about pattern. I appreciate your help on that too..  Actually to be honest, just "literally just" inclusion of the additional-methods.js file will solve the problem. Which is what i answered below, but as a courtesy of you helping out finding so many issues, i have accepted your answer.

I really thank you for help again.

Answer (score -1):

You need additional-methods.min.js from the plugin

Comment: Why did someone down vote it? This is the exact answer.